# Singleton abstraction in Typescript

Tags: typescript, singleton

I'm creating services, and I want to create single instances for these services.

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
class Service1 {
    private static instance: Service1
    
    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): Service1 {
        (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new Service1()
        }
        return this.instance
    }
}

export default Service1
```

```
class Service2 {
    private static instance: Service2
    
    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): Service2 {
        (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new Service2()
        }
        return this.instance
    }
}

export default Service2
```

```
import Service1 from '/path/to/Service1.ts'
import Service2 from '/path/to/Service2.ts'


Service1.getInstance()
Service2.getInstance()
```

It works fine, okay. But what I want is getting rid of that duplication and gathering those two service under an abstract class like this:

```
abstract class Service<T> {
    private static instance: T
    
    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): T {
        (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new T()
        }
        return this.instance
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class Service1 extends Service<Service1> {
}
```

Of course it does not work, it says that for T:

```
Static members cannot reference class type parameters
```

Also, I can not create an instance with that generic T type, obviously. Is there any way to work around this whole situation???

Comment: Please make the code a [mre] by fixing the typos; you can test it in an IDE to find them.

Comment: I don't think generics the way you're using them are going to be very useful; maybe you could write a `Singleton` factory function as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgvlvW)?  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your answer. Actually that example helped a lot. I've only made a little modification. Instead of returning an object, I've returned a class.

Comment: Sure, that was a typo you had.  But [my approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgvlvW) would be the same; return an object with a `getInstance()` method which uses the internal class constructor to make sure there's only one instance in existence.  If that doesn't work for your needs, could you demonstrate (with code) a use case where that is apparent?